# GPS coordinates adding meters with angle incorrect result

Tags: java, gps

I have this function were I want to add a distance in meters (x and y) at a given angle to existing coordinates (lat/long):

```
 * Calculates a new GPS coordinate from given coordinates and a given movement distances in meters
 *
 * @param lat0  the latitude to move from
 * @param long0 the longitude to move from
 * @param dx    the distance to move on the x axis in meters. Use positive values to move to the east(right) and negative values to move to the west(left)
 * @param dy    the distance to move on the y axis in meters. Use positive values to move to the north (up) and negative values to move to the south(down)
 * @return a new double array containing the target coordinates: [latitude, longitude]
 */
public double[] calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(double lat0, double long0, double dx, double dy) {
    double lat = lat0 + (180 / Math.PI) * (dy / 6378137);
    double lon = long0 + (180 / Math.PI) * (dx / 6378137) / Math.cos(Math.PI / 180.0 * lat0);
    return new double[]{lat, lon};
}

public double[] calculateCoodinatesAfterMove(Waypoint w, double dx, double dy, double angle) {
    return calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(w, dx * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180), dy * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180));
}

public double[] calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(double lat0, double long0, double dx, double dy, double angle) {
    return calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(lat0, long0, dx * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180), dy * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180));
}
```

I also have a function that calculates the bearing between two coordinates and I checked that this function is correct.

The problem is that the function above does not create waypoints with the specified angle.
Here is an example call where I specify an angle of 64:

```
double[] resultMove = coordinateCalculator.calculateCoordinatesAfterMove(48.993268432102354, 8.395133104531464, 10, 5, 64);
        System.out.println(resultMove[0] + ", "  +resultMove[1]);
        System.out.println("Calculated angle: " + coordinateCalculator.calculateAngleBetweenWaypoints(
                48.993268432102354, 8.395133104531464, resultMove[0], resultMove[1]
        ));
```

which gives me an calculated waypoint of:

```
48.993308802123806, 8.395193120821242
```

and a calculated angle between this and the starting point of 44.2XXX degrees which is correct (checked it here: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Latitudes and longitudes are always passed as shown in the example which should be radian. Correct me if this kind of representation is degree:)

Could someone help me why my function does not return a waypoint in the desired angle?

Comment: try it in degrees... if it works, it is degrees..

Comment: Could you explain that? What would I need to change in my code to use degree?

Comment: You're not confusing *loxodromes* and *orthodromes* are you ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark never heard of that:

Comment: Well hit up the 'net and find out the difference, it may be germane to your problem.  If not, you'll have learned two freaky new words.